# jquery calculate условие для массива

Tags: jquery

Помогите написать условие на jQuery. Есть checkbox`s check-0 - check-5 (6 штук)
Нужно условие, что если выбрано один из 2,3,4 - то цена 15000, а каждый последующий - цена - 5000. Цена на остальные чекбоксы хранится в массиве. Я так понимаю нужно через if как-то написать и передавать данные в массив на место 2,3,4

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var price = [
    [900, 28900, 16200, 22800, 4500, 6000],
    [900, 28900, 19500, 27500, 4500, 7500],
    [900, 36250, 24850, 32100, 4500, 13500]
];
function calculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    var i = $('.btn.active').find('input:radio[name="options"]').val();
    console.log(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if ($('#check-'+String(j)).is(':checked')) {
            sum += price[i][j];
            $('.cxema-'+String(j)).show();
        } else {
            $('.cxema-'+String(j)).hide();
        }
    }

    sum = String(sum).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
    console.log('Общая сумма: '+sum);
    var result = sum + ' руб.';
    $('#result span').html(result);
    return sum;
}
}
```

html

```
<div class="header-main-form">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
       <label class="btn active" id="option-00">
       <input type="radio" name="options" id="option-0" value="0" checked>
         вкладка 1
       </label>
       <label class="btn" id="option-01">
       <input type="radio" name="options" id="option-1" value="1">
           вкладка 2
       </label>
       <label class="btn" id="option-02">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option-2" value="2">
             вкладка 3
       </label>
    </div>
    <div class="check-group">
       <label id="label-0" class="clearfix" for="check-0">
       <input id="check-0" type="checkbox" checked />1й
       </label>
       <label id="label-1" class="clearfix" for="check-1">
       <input id="check-1" type="checkbox" class="discount" />2й
       </label>
       <label id="label-2" class="clearfix" for="check-2">
       <input id="check-2" type="checkbox" class="discount" />3й
       </label>
       <label id="label-3" class="clearfix" for="check-3">
       <input id="check-3" type="checkbox" class="discount" />4й
       </label>
       <label id="label-4" class="clearfix" for="check-4">
       <input id="check-4" type="checkbox" />5й
       </label>
       <label id="label-5" class="clearfix" for="check-5">
       <input id="check-5" type="checkbox" />6й
       </label>
   </div>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
var itog=0;

if ($('.discount').attr('checked')== true){
 itog=10;  // +10 к первому товару
 price=5;
}else{
 price=15;
}

itog+=price;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check-0"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-2" class="discount"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-3" class="discount"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-4" class="discount"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-5"/>
```

Comment: а как в массив это записать? var price = [
    [0, itog+=price, 0, 5000],
    [0, itog+=price, 0, 5000],
    [0, itog+=price, 5000]
];

Comment: @АлександрНитченко, я не понимаю что это за массив и что/зачем в него надо писать

Comment: добавил код в тему